# Fill all grid cells with a control template

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, grid

I want to fill all cells with the same control. What I have now is a control template and a grid. But I can't find a simple way in Xaml to add the control to all the cells.

This is the code I have right now:

```
<Window x:Class="AcMidi.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="512" Width="760">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="Planet">
            <Button Content="Button"></Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Height="209" Name="grid1" Width="500">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ItemsControl`

- Bind the `ItemsSource` to a collection of items which have properties for row postion and column position, you can easily create such a collection with two for loops.
- Make the `ItemsPanel` the `Grid`
- In the `ItemContainerStyle` you can bind the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` to the properties on your items.
- Set the `ItemTemplate` to your template (which should be a `DataTemplate` as you are not templating a control).